# Geany 1.36,PHP variable highlight dollar sign on double-click

Tags: php, geany

In Geany, when you double-click on a php variable `$example`, it highlights the word 'example' without highlighting the dollar sign ($).

How do I make geany highlight the dollar sign too?

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit two files:

`/usr/share/geany/filedefs/filetypes.php`

and

`~/.config/geany/filedefs/filetypes.conf`

Change:

`wordchars=_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789`

To:

`wordchars=_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789$`

Make sure they match character for character in both files.  Once finished reload the configuration.  `Tools>Reload Configuration`.  Alternatively you can close and re-open Geany.

For more information visit the [Geany Plugin API Documentation](https://www.geany.org/manual/reference/editor_8h.html)